# What steps can I take to optimize the network bandwidth output of hping3 in WSL for Windows Wi-Fi network?

Tags: networking, windows-subsystem-for-linux

we are producing an application to test our servers. Hping3 is an application that we are running, however we have a problem while processing this tool at WSL (Windows subsystem for linux) , there is no problem to see actual bandwidth which is produced by hping but this power is looking so low at Windows Wi-Fi network interface. How can we solve this problem. Could you please help us if you have an idea on it ?

I sent a packet to a destination with the hping3 tool from wsl. With the configurations I specified for hping3, I aim to see the bandwith output from the network and to see approximately similar values in the target ip address.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** It's unclear to me what version of the Ubuntu OS you're running. Please edit your question to include this information as it may help in resolving your issue. Thanks

Comment: Just tested `hping3` on WSL, Ubuntu 22. Worked as expected for me. Can you edit your question to include exactly what you ran, what output you saw, and what output you expected?